# Need help with this differential equation problem involving second derivative and first derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I have been trying to solve this problem.
I was able to observe that from the given conditions $x^2 + f^2(x) + (f'(x))^2 = c$, where c is some constant, but it does not help me in any of the options.

Any hints or ideas would be appreciated

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function that assumes real values satisfying the equation: $x+f(x)f'(x)+f'(x)f''(x)=0 \forall x \in (-1,1)$, then which of the following is/are correct?

A) $ \lim_{x\to0}xf(x) = -1$

B) $ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f'(x)}{ln|x|} = 0$

C) $ \lim_{x\to0}xf(x)f'(x) = 1$

D) $ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)f'(x)}{ln|x|} = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ and $f'$ are continuous at $x=0$, they are bounded in a neighbourhood of $0$ as well. Hence you always have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x f(x)f'(x)=0.$$
Therefore A) and C) cannot be.

Let us rewrite the equation a bit by dividing by $f'$:
$$\frac{x}{f'(x)} + f(x) + f''(x)=0.$$
If we choose $f'(0)\neq 0$ and $f(0)\neq 0$, then this initial value problem has a unique solution by Picard-Lindelöfs theorem. Again by continuity $f$ and $f'$ would be bounded away from zero at $x=0$. Therefore
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(x)}{\ln |x|} = \pm \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)f'(x)}{\ln |x|} = 0$$

Because f(x) and f'(x) are bounded the above limits are intuitive.

Comment: How did you conclude that $lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{ln|x|}$ = $\infty$? From the conclusion that f'(x) is bounded and the fact that in the neighborhood of zero ln|x| is infinitely large shouldn't the limit be 0?

Comment: The options written by me initially were incorrect, just the fact that f(x) and f'(x) are bounded is sufficient for the problem. The correct answer is B and D. Thanks